# How can I get corner coordinates of rotated CCNode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCNode with a certain rotation. For the sake of simplicity lets say its rotated 45 degrees, size is 100*100 and position is 200,200.

[image: Example]

I'm looking to find the 4 corner coordinates (marked as green) on this image. Is there any method in the framework that I can use for this or do I need to do it manually with trigonomery? In that case how can I do that the easiest way?

The best thing is if I could make this a method in the CCNode class so its easily accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCNode.h:

```
/** Converts a Point to world space coordinates. The result is in Points.
 @since v0.7.1
 */
- (CGPoint)convertToWorldSpace:(CGPoint)nodePoint;

/** Converts a Point to node (local) space coordinates. The result is in Points.
 @since v0.7.1
 */
- (CGPoint)convertToNodeSpace:(CGPoint)worldPoint;
```

Example:

```
// top right corner of your node 
CGPoint topRight = ccp(node.contentSize.width, node.contentSize.height);
// same point in world coordinates
CGPoint topRightWorld = [node convertToWorldSpace:topRight];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CGFloat angle = node.rotation * M_PI / 180;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(node.position.x, node.position.y, node.contentSize.width, node.contentSize.height);

CGPoint ip0 = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x,frame.origin.y);
CGPoint ip1 = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x +frame.size.width, 0);
CGPoint ip2 = CGPointMake(0,frame.origin.y +frame.size.height);
CGPoint ip3 = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x +frame.size.width,frame.origin.y +frame.size.height);

ip0 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(ip0, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));
ip1 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(ip1, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));
ip2 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(ip2, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));
ip3 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(ip3, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This probably works too, if you are not working with CCNode or any base class of it this might be the way to go.